# An alternative definition for expected value?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I'm struggling with proving the following claim:

$\mathbb{E}_{x \sim D}[x] = \arg\min_{u \in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{E}_{x\sim D}[|x-u|]$.

Is it true? If so, how to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

That is not correct - the right-hand side provides the median(s) rather than the mean

As an illustration, suppose $D$ is the distribution taking values $\{0,3,15\}$ with equal probability:

- with $u=3$ the median, you have $\mathbb{E}_{x\sim D}[|x-u|] = \frac13 \times 3 + \frac13 \times 0 + \frac13 \times 12 = 5$
- with $u=6$ the mean, you have $\mathbb{E}_{x\sim D}[|x-u|] = \frac13 \times 6 + \frac13 \times 3 + \frac13 \times 9 = 6$ which is more

To get the mean in a similar way, you could use $\arg\min_{u \in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{E}_{x\sim D}[(x-u)^2]$.  For a proof, multiply out and take the derivative with respect to $u$

In my example:

- with $u=3$ the median, you have $\mathbb{E}_{x\sim D}[(x-u)^2] = \frac13 \times 9 + \frac13 \times 0 + \frac13 \times 144 = 51$
- with $u=6$ the mean, you have $\mathbb{E}_{x\sim D}[(x-u)^2] = \frac13 \times 36 + \frac13 \times 9 + \frac13 \times 81 = 42$ which is less